# Is it okay to add an image to somebody else's question?

Tags: discussion, images, policy

I kind of did it before asking this on [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5268/where-in-india-can-one-wash-and-play-with-elephants), and it occurred to me that some people might not like it --after all it's their own question. Do you think it's acceptable to do it, and if yes, when?

I think it's valuable sometimes to have a picture, and from promotional perspective, posts with pictures tend to attract more upvotes and attention. In this case it's pretty clear cut IMO, but I'd like to hear from others as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's ok if it adds to the question, ie helps to make it clearer what the person is after.  If they're talking about bathing elephants, the mental image may boggle some people, so a picture is helpful.  If however, they're asking about [speaking only English in India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/407/will-i-be-able-to-travel-around-india-speaking-only-english), for example, that's going to be less helpful to add a picture to - as it won't add to the question in a useful manner.

I'm all for it, personally, as long as it improves or assists the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll roll it back

Comment: No no, I liked it! Re-read :)  I'm happy with it in this case, as it adds to the question by showing what they mean.  Whereas something about language, or country counting clearly wouldn't need an image.

Comment: Haha, I was too quick about it and didn't pay attention to this. Rolled it once more -- the question should feel like a pig being roasted by now.

Comment: What? A motivational poster featuring Samuel L Jackson wouldn't be appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

Questions and answers on StackExchange sites are collaboratively edited, [like in a wiki](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#editing). Adding images to questions as long as they are relevant and properly licensed/cited is okay.

Comment: Yep Stack Exchange is about the long term and the long tail. Questions have OPs but they don't really have owners. We shouldn't put words into the OP's mouth but we should improve the questions and the answers by fixing formatting, spelling, readability, pictures, etc.

Comment: Going to comment here. As [one who was accused of plagiarism for posting non-cited pictures....](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38842/i-saw-a-lakeside-castle-or-hotel-from-the-air-north-of-newark-what-is-it/38843#38843) please ensure you use wiki-commons or otherwise authorized/allowed photos.